# Start Google Music in background from My Application

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service

I'm having issues sending a media action to Google Music from inside my application. Originally I was using `android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON` with the action set to the media key I wanted to send, which was fine, till an update in CM10.1 seems to have stopped this from working for some odd reason (I'm guessing something else gets to the intent first). When this method worked, Google Music would open up if it wasn't already running and act on the command I had sent to it.

I've since changed this to `com.android.music.musicservicecommand` with an action of `command` followed by the action (`play` for example) which works perfectly now, but only if Google Music is currently running in the background. I've been looking through the manifest of the Google Music app for over an hour now, looking for an exported service I could trigger to start it up (after checking if it's already running or not), but I can't find anything to help me out. I don't really want to start it in the foreground if I can avoid it.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to send my media command in a way which will always open Google Music and send a command (as it used to for me), or a way of opening Google Music in the background (either a service, or an activity with no visible elements)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did u get a solution for this? I have the same problem..